# Genymotion 3.0.1 Stuck and not starting after installation

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion

[image: Screenshot of genymotion]

I installed a virtual box 6.1 and Genymotion 3.0.1 but it is not starting it is stuck.
Any Idea how can I solve this problem?
- OS windows 10
- Genymotion 3.0.1
- Virtual box Oracle 6.1

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS settings may not enabled support virtualization, or the processor may not support virtualization, or there may not be enough RAM.

Answer (score 0):

VirtualBox 6.1 does not work very well with Genymotion on Windows 10. You should try to downgrade VirtualBox to 6.0.4, which is Genymotion recommended version.